# Misuse of [clr]

Tags: discussion, tags

It concerns me that [clr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clr), which should be assigned to questions regarding Common Language Runtime, is usually assigned to multiple heavily unrelated questions, including ones about [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and mostly [c++-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli), which is almost always forgotten in the tags section (usually replaced with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and *even* [managed-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/managed-c%2b%2b)).

Now I have attempted to purge wrong usage of the tag, but the amount of questions is a bit high. What should be done with this problem? Seeing the majority of questions tagged with this is a mistake, I would consider burning the tag and sowing it with salt, but there are also rightly tagged questions, whose only other tags are [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/net).

See the examples:

[clr stored procedures with two in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503347/clr-stored-procedures-with-two-in-parameters)
 - about "clr stored procedures". Correctly tagged with [sqlclr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlclr), but [clr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clr) is completely reduntant and irrelevant.

[Using a C# class from a managed C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521244/using-a-c-sharp-class-from-a-managed-c-project) - about C++/CLI. Not related to CLR, and [c++-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) is missing. Also abhorrently tagged with [managed-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/managed-c%2b%2b).

[c++/clr StructureToPtr exit application without any exception or error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038069/c-clr-structuretoptr-exit-application-without-any-exception-or-error) - only [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [clr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clr). The "tag" is included in the name.

[How CLR knows type of [unboxed] Value Type variable at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791272/how-clr-knows-type-of-unboxed-value-type-variable-at-runtime) - perfectly on-topic for the tag.

---

So, what would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Not familiar with most of the tags at hand, but any indication why it's being misused? Is it being confused for something else? Perhaps renaming to something more explicit like `common-language-runtime` would help?

Comment: Gross and annoying overloading of words/terms is rife in software development:(   'static' and 'interrupt' seem to get a new meaning every month:(   For TLA's, it's even worse:(

Comment: The tags are usually corrected by whomever answers the question.  But several of the ones you quoted are trash questions that will never get an answer.  They can't get closed because there are never enough users available to look at them, tags like [clr], [managed-c++] and [c++-cli] are too small.  And it is not worth the free time of a few overworked users to relabel trash.  They'll get automatically deleted eventually.  So don't worry about it.  Please don't fix this problem either, you'll re-activate a lot of trash.